# DustJS logic to verify empty string

Tags: node.js, dust.js, dust-helpers

I need to write logic to check whether the value is empty or it has string. Any help on this.. i tried this following. but it doesn't work in nodejs and throwing error

```
{@if cond="'{notes}' != '' || '{errors}' != '' "}
   display html
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you for asking this. It's hard to find good Dust.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The `@if` helper is deprecated and should not be used. However, based on the code you've given, you should probably be able to use an [exists](http://www.dustjs.com/docs/syntax/#exists) check.

```
{?notes}
  {?errors}
    {! Display HTML !}
  {/errors}
{/notes}
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you could use the `@ne` helper.

```
{@ne key=notes value=""}
   ...
{/ne}
```

If that still isn't good enough, you could try writing a context helper. The [documentation](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/context-helpers/) on dustjs.com is excellent.

Comment: Wouldn't the above code `&&` instead of `||` on both the fields ?

Answer (score 0):

```
{?notes}
  Display HTML
{:else}
  {?errors}
    Display HTML
  {/errors}
{/notes}
```

should do the trick.